# how to change div content with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

How do i change a div with another div using javascript??

I want to change the content of the div but it is all plain text and no style and i want it to be styled. is there a way to change the content or do i need to change the whole div and how? i have no clue!!

this is the site: http://www.websteam.nl/index2.html

thanks in advance!

what i have is this:

```
function wijzigTekst(inhoud) {document.getElementById('transbox').innerHTML = inhoud; }
```

And this is the html:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li id="nav-1"><a href="#" onmousedown="wijzigTekst('hoi')">Home</a></li>
<li id="nav-2"><a href="#" onmousedown="wijzigTekst('transsbox')">School</a></li>
<li id="nav-3"><a href="#" onmousedown="wijzigTekst('is')">Over Websteam</a></li>
<li id="nav-4"><a href="#" onmousedown="wijzigTekst('de')">Contact</a></li>
<li id="nav-5"><a href="#" onmousedown="wijzigTekst('tekst')">Project</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: If you want them to be styled, use CSS. The code you have should be fine, assuming you pass correct HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Create CSS style, add the content to the div and it will take the style automatically

CSS

```
h1{
    border:solid 2px #009;
    padding:5px 0px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function changediv(){
    var div = document.getElementById("divData");
    div.innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:changediv();">Change Data</a>
<div id="divData"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

or by using jquery :

CSS

```
#text {
    /* style */
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="transbox">
    <div id="text"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#transbox #text').html('your text');
```

Comment: he needs javascript ..Smoky

Comment: @sasi he did tag it with jQuery.